# C# Caesar's Cipher

Tags: c#

I'm taking a c# course and I'm quite confused on why this isn't working.
Here is the instructions:

> Create a string variable named decodedString and set it equal to the contents of the StringTextBox.
>
> Create a string variable named encodedString to hold the encoded string and set it equal to an empty string.  We will build up the encoded values letter-by-letter in this variable.
>
> Use a for() loop to loop through all of the characters in decodedString.  Your loop index "i" should start at 0 and increment up to the last character in decodedString.
>
> Inside the loop:
>   Create a char variable named thisChar and set it equal to the current character decodedString[i].
>
> Create an integer variable named encodedValue and set it equal to the ASCII numeric value of the character stored in thisChar.  To do this you can simply cast the character into an int as shown below:
>   int encodedValue = (int)thisChar;
>
> Use a string format statement (either String.Format() or ToString() ) to convert the encodedValue integer into a 3-digit text string, with leading zeros where needed.  Append the resulting string to the end of the encodedString variable.
>   Also append a comma "," to the end of the encodedString after each set of 3 digits.
>   When your loop is done, your encodedString should hold the fully encoded results.  Show the results to the user by setting the StringTextBox.Text equal to the encodedString.

My code

```
private void EnocodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String decodeString = StringTextBox.Text;
        String encodeString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < decodeString.Length; i++)
        {

            Char thisChar = decodeString{i};
            int encodedValue = (int)thisChar;
            encodeString = encodedValue.ToString("D3");
            StringTextBox.Text = encodeString;

        }
```

Comment: @Erresen That seemed to fix it but I can only encode 3 letters at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Change `decodeString{i}` to `decodeString[i]`

You also need to append the result with

```
encodeString = $"{encodeString}{encodedValue.ToString("D3")},";
```

This is called string interpolation, and it's a more readable version of String.Format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings

To more fully comply with the specification you’ve provided (and to not use string interpolation), the encode string line could be:

```
encodeString = encodeString + encodedValue.ToString("D3") + “,”;
```

Comment: WOW, that fixed both my problems that you so much. But now I'm confused on how the   encodeString = $"{encodeString}{encodedValue.ToString("D3")}";  statement works

Comment: the encode string line uses string interpolation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings

Comment: Perhaps it was down voted (not by me) because although string interpolation is a useful new C# v6 feature, it is not a good fit for all situations.  First, there is no need to interpolate the redundant call to `ToString` when the entire purpose of string interpolation is to format strings with less typing.  Next, simple string concatenation can be done with the + operator, so no need to complicate the operation.  The following code has the same result:  `encodeString += $"{encodedValue:D3},"`.

Comment: Updated answer to include an option that doesn’t include interpolation

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the value of `StringTextBox.Text` after each iteration. Also, you're not appending commas. You can collect the encoded values in a list then, after the loop ends, update the textbox's text field:

```
private void EnocodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String decodeString = StringTextBox.Text;
    String encodedString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < decodeString.Length; i++)
    {

        Char thisChar = decodeString[i];
        int encodedValue = (int)thisChar;
        encodedString += encodedValue.ToString("D3") + ",";
    }

    StringTextBox.Text = encodedString;
}
```